# error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I know this question is asked before but solutions doesn't fix my problem.

That's why I wanted to ask again. Because I have tried with ES5, ES6, ES2018, ES2015, ES2015.promise etc..

**Background.js**

```
async function run() {
    
    setInterval(()=>{
        console.log("Hello world");
    },3000);

}

async function getTab() {
    const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({});
    return tabs[0];
}

setInterval(async function(){
    const tab = await getTab();
    console.log(tab);

    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
      {
        target: {tabId: tab.id, allFrames: true},
        func: run,
      },
      (injectionResults) => { 
    
        console.log("what is happening here",injectionResults);
      });
},5000);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [ "es2018", "dom" ]
    }
}
```

> tsc Background.ts

getting this error

```
error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.

Background.ts:7:16 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.

7 async function run() {
                 ~~~

Background.ts:20:13 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.

20 setInterval(async function(){
```

Comment: `typescript` package version please? 4.5.5 is compiling `background.ts` without any problem.

Comment: However, I tried with `"lib": ["es5", "dom"],` in `tsconfig.json`, and it produced the same error as OP mentions. But the given `tsconfig.json` works fine for me.

Comment: tsc --version -> 4.5.5

Answer (score 2):

tsc command is probably not picking up the tsconfig.json file.
I think it happens when you specify the source file in the command line.
It was showing me error when I ran `tsc index.ts` but not when I simply ran `tsc`.
I don't know how that changes with different file names though.